# Pgfplot from table - restrict x domain not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I create the following chart:
[image]

With this code:

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

%colors
\usepackage{color} % colors
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{colourone}{RGB}{18,32,132} % 22,131,198
\definecolor{colourtwo}{RGB}{202,211,43}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=space]{
date donate volunteer Oxfam
2004 21.3 78.6 0
2005 21.9 76.1 0
2006 17.3 65.5 0
2007 17.2 57.2 0
2008 18.8 56.2 0
2009 18.7 57.5 0
2010 20.8 56.4 0
2011 20.9 50.8 0
2012 20.6 49.1 8.4
2013 21.4 47.8 7.6
2014 24.4 47.3 7.3
2015 24.3 46.0 6.3
2016 26.3 45.3 5.8
2017 29.4 45.9 5.8
2018 29.8 44.3 20.0
2019 30.8 45.8 5.2
2020 45.5 47.3 4.0
}\chart

\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \draw[ ##1,/tikz/.cd,yshift=-0.25em]
            (0cm,0cm) rectangle (0.6em,0.6em);},},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\small
\begin{axis}[
ymajorgrids,
grid style = gray!30!white,
x=8.5mm,
bar width=3mm,
axis lines=left,
axis x line shift=0,
enlarge x limits=0,
enlarge y limits={0, upper},
%
% y ticks style and label
ylabel={Index},
ylabel shift = 1pt,
ymin=0,
ymax = 101,
ytick distance = 10,
axis y line*=right,
%y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=1, /tikz/.cd, font=\scriptsize},
%
% x axis ticks and style
xticklabel shift={0pt},
xtick=data,
xticklabels from table={\chart}{date},  
table/x expr = \coordindex,                     
x tick label style = {rotate=0},
%
% legends and labels
legend style = {fill = none, draw=none,
    legend columns=-1,
    at={(0.5,1.13)},
    anchor=north,
    /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=2em},
},
]
%
% done with the axis, now the plots   
\addplot [draw = black, mark = x] table [y=donate] {\chart};
\addlegendentry{Donate}; 
\addplot [draw = red, mark = x] table [y=volunteer] {\chart};
\addlegendentry{Volunteer};
\addplot [draw = gray, mark = x] table [y=Oxfam] {\chart};
\addlegendentry{Oxfam};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to restrict the domain for the Oxfam plot to be from 2012 to 2020 only. I've tried `restrict x to domain=2012:2020` without success. How do I achieve this?

Comment: One hacky solution I had was to change all the Oxfam values between 2004-2011 from `0` to `-4` since I have `ymin = 0`, but I'd like something 'proper'.

Comment: Another solution - `restrict y to domain = 1:100`. But again, I'd like to know how to do this by restricting the x-domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have `table/x expr = \coordindex` the actual x-values used in the plot is from 0 to 16, and `restrict x to domain` applies to those values.

Options:

- `restrict x to domain=8:16`
- `\addplot [draw = gray, mark = x, x filter/.expression={\thisrow{date}>2011 ? x : nan}] table [y=Oxfam] {\chart};`

  This `x filter` does the filtering based on the actual values in the data table.
- Remove `table/x expr = \coordindex` from the `axis` options, and use the `restrict x to domain` setting you suggested. (I would probably use `xtick distance=1,xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/set thousands separator=}` instead of `xtick=data` and reading the ticklabels from the table, but in your case you get the same.)